fsck is modifying file system now on every boot on Ubuntu 22.04
I once had a dual boot on this system with Windows 10, but I reinstalled a fresh single boot Ubuntu installation because I was not needing Windows 10 anymore and it was causing issues with the filesystem booting in read-only mode. Since then I must have had problems after I changed to a single boot Ubuntu, but I didn't journal them. I see in the grub file I have fsck.mode=force and fsck.repair=yes in the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT line. So this was when I would have had problems after installing Ubuntu on its own without Windows.
So for the past 5-10 boots, fsck has started modifying the file system every boot, which has worried me a bit. Fortunately my system has been working normally and I have not noticed any problems or missing files yet.
Should I remove fsck from grub because I do not want my file system to change dramatically and lose data? It would be cool to learn more about this. My laptop has an NVMe drive. I have one partition mounted at /boot/efi and a second for the filesystem root (/dev/nvme0n1p2) I will attach some screenshots of the boot.
Checking inodes:

File system was modified:


What it is attempting to do is REPAIR the file system. Your hard disk is dead or dying. You said there were issues before.

I have an nvme drive, i hope you noticed that, its roughly 2-3 years old. Maybe all the reinstalling of operating systems has helped it die quicker, but I doubt that its dying. Surely something else is wrong
